# Deleting temp files in batch file

Tags: batch-file, scripting, temp

Just building a batch file to delete temp files on my vista machines @ home that I want to add to task scheduler. I have this so far, but I get  a lot of access denied, and it never finds a thumbs.db file or index.dat and there are heaps of them. What am I doing wrong?

```
 attrib +a -s -h -r "%windir%\Temp\*.*" /s
  del /f /s /q "%windir%\Temp\*.*" >>"logs\temp.txt"

 attrib +a -s -h -r "thumbs.db" /s
  del /s /f /q "thumbs.db" >>"logs\temp.txt"

 attrib +a -s -h -r *.tmp.log /s
  del /s /f /q "*.tmp.log" >>"logs\temp.txt"

 attrib +a -s -h -r “%userprofile%\Application Data\Microsoft\Office\Recent\*.*” /s
  del /f /q /s “%userprofile%\Application Data\Microsoft\Office\Recent\*.*” >>"logs\temp.txt"

 attrib +a -s -h -r "%systemdrive%\*.gid" /s
  del /s /f / q "%systemdrive%\*.gid" >>"logs\temp.txt"

 attrib +a -s -h -r "%systemdrive%\*.fts" /s
  del /s /f /q "%systemdrive%\*.fts" >>"logs\temp.txt"

 attrib +a -s -h -r "%systemdrive%\*.cnt" /s
  del /s /f /q "%systemdrive%\*.cnt" >>"logs\temp.txt"

 attrib +a -s -h -r "%systemdrive%\*.old" /s
  del /s /f /q "%systemdrive%\*.old" >>"logs\temp.txt"

 attrib +a -s -h -r "%systemdrive%\*.diz" /s
  del /s /f /q "%systemdrive%\*.diz" >>"logs\temp.txt"

 attrib +a -s -h -r "%systemdrive%\*.bak" /s
  del /s /f /q "%systemdrive%\*.bak" >>"logs\temp.txt"

 attrib +a -s -h -r "%systemdrive%\*.tmp" /s
  del /s /f /q "%systemdrive%\*.tmp" >>"logs\temp.txt"

 attrib +a -s -h -r "%systemdrive%\*.chk" /s
  del /s /f /q "%systemdrive%\*.chk" >>"logs\temp.txt"

 attrib +a -s -h -r "%systemdrive%\*.dmp" /s
  del /s /f /q "%systemdrive%\*.dmp" >>"logs\temp.txt"

 attrib +a -s -h -r "%systemdrive%\*.00?" /s
  del /s /f /q "%systemdrive%\*.00?" >>"logs\temp.txt"

 attrib +a -s -h -r "%systemdrive%\index.dat" /s
  del /s /f /q "%systemdrive%\index.dat" >>"logs\temp.txt"

 attrib +a -s -h -r "%systemdrive%\fw*log.txt" /s
  del /s /f /q "%systemdrive%\fw*log.txt" >>"logs\temp.txt"

 attrib +a -s -h -r "%systemdrive%\zalog*.txt" /s
  del /s /f /q "%systemdrive%\zalog*.txt" >>"logs\temp.txt"

 attrib +a -s -h -r "%systemdrive%\backup*.rdb" /s
  del /s /f /q "%systemdrive%\backup*.rdb" >>"logs\temp.txt"

 attrib +a -s -h -r "%systemdrive%\*._mp" /s  
  del /f /s /q %systemdrive%\*._mp >>"logs\temp.txt"

 attrib +a -s -h -r "%systemdrive%\*.log" /s 
  del /f /s /q "%systemdrive%\*.log" >>"logs\temp.txt"

 attrib +a -s -h -r "%systemdrive%\Temp\*.*" /s
  del /f /s /q "%systemdrive%\Temp\*.*" >>"logs\temp.txt"

 attrib +a -s -h -r "%systemdrive%\Users\Default\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\History\*.*" /s
  del /f /s /q "%systemdrive%\Users\Default\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\History\*.*" >>"logs\temp.txt"

 attrib +a -s -h -r "%systemdrive%\Users\Default\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Temporary Internet Files\*.*" /s
  del /f /s /q "%systemdrive%\Users\Default\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Temporary Internet Files\*.*" >>"logs\temp.txt"

 attrib +a -s -h -r "%systemdrive%\Users\Default\AppData\Local\Temp\*.*" /s
  del /f /s /q "%systemdrive%\Users\Default\AppData\Local\Temp\*.*" >>"logs\temp.txt"

 attrib +a -s -h -r "%systemdrive%\Users\Default\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Cookies\*.*" /s
  del /f /s /q "%systemdrive%\Users\Default\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Cookies\*.*" >>"logs\temp.txt"

 attrib +a -s -h -r "%systemdrive%\Users\Default\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Recent\*.*" /s
  del /f /s /q "%systemdrive%\Users\Default\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Recent\*.*" >>"logs\temp.txt"

 attrib +a -s -h -r "%systemdrive%\Windows\Downloaded Program Files\*.*" /s
  del /f /s /q "%systemdrive%\Windows\Downloaded Program Files\*.*" >>"logs\temp.txt"

 attrib +a -s -h -r "%ProgramData%\Apple\Installer Cache\*.*" /s 
  del /f /s /q "%ProgramData%\Apple\Installer Cache\*.*" >>"logs\temp.txt"

 attrib +a -s -h -r "%ProgramData%\Apple Computer\Installer Cache\*.*" /s
  del /f /s /q "%ProgramData%\Apple Computer\Installer Cache\*.*" >>"logs\temp.txt"

 attrib +a -s -h -r "%ProgramData%\Microsoft\Search\Data\Temp\*.*" /s
  del /f /s /q "%ProgramData%\Microsoft\Search\Data\Temp\*.*" >>"logs\temp.txt"

 attrib +a -s -h -r "%ProgramData%\Temp\*.*" /s
  del /f /s /q "%ProgramData%\Temp\*.*" >>"logs\temp.txt"

 attrib +a -s -h -r "%appdata%\Adobe\Flash Player\AssetCache\*.*" /s
  del /f /s /q "%appdata%\Adobe\Flash Player\AssetCache\*.*" >>"logs\temp.txt"

 attrib +a -s -h -r "%appdata%\Macromedia\Flash Player\#SharedObjects\*.*" /s
  del /f /s /q "%appdata%\Macromedia\Flash Player\#SharedObjects\*.*" >>"logs\temp.txt"

 attrib +a -s -h -r "%appdata%\Macromedia\Flash Player\macromedia.com\support\flashplayer\sys\*.*" /s
  del /f /s /q "%appdata%\Macromedia\Flash Player\macromedia.com\support\flashplayer\sys\*.*" >>"logs\temp.txt"

 attrib +a -s -h -r "%appdata%\Macromedia\Flash Player\macromedia.com\support\flashplayer\sys\*.*" /s
  del /f /s /q "%appdata%\Macromedia\Flash Player\macromedia.com\support\flashplayer\sys\*.*" >>"logs\temp.txt"

 attrib +a -s -h -r "%appdata%\Microsoft\Windows\Cookies\*.*" /s
  del /f /s /q "%appdata%\Microsoft\Windows\Cookies\*.*" >>"logs\temp.txt"

 attrib +a -s -h -r "%appdata%\Microsoft\Windows\Recent\*.*" /s
  del /f /s /q "%appdata%\Microsoft\Windows\Recent\*.*" >>"logs\temp.txt"

 attrib +a -s -h -r "%appdata%\Mozilla\Firefox\Crash Reports\*.*" /s
  del /f /s /q "%appdata%\Mozilla\Firefox\Crash Reports\*.*" >>"logs\temp.txt"

 attrib +a -s -h -r "%appdata%\Sun\Java\Deployment\cache*.*" /s
  del /f /s /q "%appdata%\Sun\Java\Deployment\cache*.*" >>"logs\temp.txt"

 attrib +a -s -h -r "%appdata%\uTorrent\*.*" /s
  del /f /s /q "%appdata%\uTorrent\*.*" >>"logs\temp.txt"

 attrib +a -s -h -r "%userprofile%\AppData\Local\Temp" /s
  del /f /s /q "%userprofile%\AppData\Local\Temp" >>"logs\temp.txt"

 attrib +a -s -h -r "%userprofile%\AppData\LocalLow\Temp" /s
  del /f /s /q "%userprofile%\AppData\LocalLow\Temp" >>"logs\temp.txt"

 attrib +a -s -h -r "%userprofile%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows Photo Gallery\Original Images\*.*" /s 
  del /f /s /q "%userprofile%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows Photo Gallery\original Images\*.*" >>"logs\temp.txt"

 attrib +a -s -h -r "%userprofile%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Burn\*.*" /s 
  del /f /s /q "%userprofile%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Burn\*.*" >>"logs\temp.txt"

 attrib +a -s -h -r "%userprofile%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Explorer\*.*" /s 
  del /f /s /q "%userprofile%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Explorer\*.*" >>"logs\temp.txt"

 attrib +a -s -h -r "%userprofile%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\History\*.*" /s 
  del /f /s /q "%userprofile%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\History\*.*" >>"logs\temp.txt"

 attrib +a -s -h -r "%userprofile%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Temporary Internet Files\*.*" /s 
  del /f /s /q "%userprofile%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Temporary Internet Files\*.*" >>"logs\temp.txt"

 attrib +a -s -h -r "%userprofile%\AppData\Local\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\*\Cache\*.*" /s
  del /f /s /q "%userprofile%\AppData\Local\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\*\Cache\*.*" >>"logs\temp.txt"

 attrib +a -s -h -r "%userprofile%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Explorer\*.db" /s
  del /f /s /q "%userprofile%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Explorer\*.db" >>"logs\temp.txt"

 attrib +a -s -h -r "%appdata%\Microsoft\Windows\cookies\*.*" /s
  del /f /s /q "%appdata%\Microsoft\Windows\cookies\*.*"  >>"logs\temp.txt"

 attrib +a -s -h -r "%appdata%\Microsoft\Windows\Recent\*.*" /s
  del /f /s /q "%appdata%\Microsoft\Windows\Recent\*.*" >>"logs\temp.txt"

 attrib +a -s -h -r "%windir%\prefetch\*.*" /s
  del /f /s /q "%windir%\prefetch\*.*" >>"logs\temp.txt"

 attrib +a -s -h -r "%windir%\SoftwareDistribution\Download\*.*" /s
  del /f /s /q "%windir%\SoftwareDistribution\Download\*.*" >>"logs\temp.txt"
```

Comment: Why not try to run the batch file from the Administrator console?

Comment: That might get rid of the permission denied errors (not necessarily, since the Adminstrator doesn't have access to everything by default). But that probably makes the parts with %userprofile% pretty useless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing that the reason you're getting access denied is because the user running the script doesn't have delete rights to the files in question or perhaps even access rights to the folders.

As for the thumbs.db and index.dat files, these are hidden and/or system files so won't get picked up by the plain delete command. You need to use /A:H and/or /A:S

Answer (score 2):

Did you remember to set the target folder when setting new attributes and deleting?

Here is a sample for deleting thumbs files, targeting network:

```
attrib +a -s -h -r \\your-sample-network-path\thumbs.db /s
del /s /f /q \\your-sample-network-path\thumbs.db
```